# How do you make the selected QListView item visible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistview

I am new to Python.  I have a Python form with 2 PyQt5 Qlistviews (LV).  There is an available and a selected listview.  I can load the available LV and see it's contents.  I can check an item to be moved to the selected LV, press a button and the item moves but it's text isn't visible in the selected LV.

```
def Add_Button_click(self):
    # Add the available item to the selected box.
    self.sel_model = QStandardItemModel(self.Selected_List)
    # Loop through the available model finding items that have been checked.

    for index in range(self.avail_model.rowCount()):
        item = self.avail_model.item(index)
        # Add the item to the selected model
        if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.sel_model.appendRow(item)
    self.Selected_List.setModel(self.sel_model)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `QStandardItem` can not belong to 2 models, so if you want to move it you must first remove it using `takeRow()`, and then insert it into the new model. Doing it directly can bring problems since the row to be deleted will change the `rowCount()`, it is best to do it in reverse.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        avail_modelLV = QtWidgets.QListView()
        sel_modelLV = QtWidgets.QListView()
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Select")
        lay.addWidget(avail_modelLV)
        lay.addWidget(button)
        lay.addWidget(sel_modelLV)

        button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        self.avail_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.sel_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()

        avail_modelLV.setModel(self.avail_model)
        sel_modelLV.setModel(self.sel_model)
        for text in ["text1", "text2", "text3", "text4"]:
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
            it.setCheckable(True)
            self.avail_model.appendRow(it)

    def on_clicked(self):
        self.sel_model.clear()
        for row in reversed(range(self.avail_model.rowCount())):
            it = self.avail_model.item(row)
            if it.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                it = self.avail_model.takeRow(row)
                self.sel_model.insertRow(0, it)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```